# if jump vs function jump

Tags: c, function, assembly

I know the jump in the memory of `if` statment is more faster than a jump of a function call.

I want to know how much `if` statement jump is faster than the function jump?

I  m looking for approximative value like:

The `if` jump is faster 10 times x function jump

Note: my cpu has a mips architecture.

Comment: Why don't you measure it yourself...? The answer on my computer will not be true for yours...

Comment: Benchmarking? There are so many architectures and configurations and situations, there can't be a definite answer for this.

Comment: @Thomas could you provide a c program to measure the difference

Comment: @MOHAMED No; this isn't a code writing service. Do it yourself or hire somebody.

Comment: @rightfold. I mean are there some links which contains a such programs or explanation to develop a uch program

Comment: You've got [a silver badge in C](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/52/c?userid=1003575), maybe you could write it, don't you think...? :)

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the number of [cycles per instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycles_per_instruction) for each case.

As it is more complicated that you seem think, I suggest you to read the link that I gave, it takes your CPU as first example.